# How do I skip the first iteration of an $.each()?

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON list that I want to iterate over, but skip the first entry, like thus:

```
$.each(
    data.collection,
    function() { DoStuffButOnlyIfNotTheFirstOne(); }
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Is this good enough?

```
$.each(data.collection.slice(1), DoStuff);
```

Answer (score 16):

```
$.each(
    data.collection,
    function(i) {
        if(i)
            DoStuffButOnlyIfNotTheFirstOne();
    }
);
```

or, probably more efficiently:

```
$.each(
    data.collection.slice(1),
    function() {
        DoStuff();
    }
);
```

Comment: i like that, even though its slightly less readable then accepted solution.

Comment: I mostly like the use of the slice(1). Very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove the first one and then use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each) without any condition (it might increase your performance for large set of arrays)

```
var collection = data.collection.slice(0 , 1);
$.each(collection,function() {
   DoStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the good old firstFlag approach:

```
var firstFlag = true;
$.each(
data.collection,
  function() { 
    if(!firstFlag) DoStuffButOnlyIfNotTheFirstOne(); 
    firstFlag = false;
}
```

But instead, I'd recommend that you filter your data collection first to remove the first item using a selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(
    data.collection,
    function(i) { if (i>0) DoStuffButOnlyIfNotTheFirstOne(); }
);
```